# init ApolloServer in specific path

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have these lines of code to init an ApolloServer and it works fine

```
const server = new ApolloServer({schema, executor});
return server.listen(port).then(({url}) => {});
```

I would like to change the URL, doing this

```
return server.listen(port).then(({"dev.cold.net"}) => {});
```

but I have a compilation error:

```
TS2339: Property 'dev.cold.net' does not exist on type 'ServerInfo'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The path is hard-coded when using the `apollo-server` package -- there is no way to change it. If you need to supply a custom path, use `apollo-server-express` instead.

```
const app = express();
const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/some-custom-path' });

app.listen({ port: 4000 }, () =>
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`)
);
```